# Mongoose error when running node

Tags: express, mongoose

When I run node server.js in terminal, I receive the following error from mongoose:

```
/Users/XXXX/Desktop/Projects/crud/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/lib/server.js:235
        process.nextTick(function() { throw err; })
                                      ^
Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:27017
    at Object.exports._errnoException (util.js:860:11)
    at exports._exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:883:20)
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1063:14)
```

I've ran npm install mongoose with a warning, but I doubt that's the reason the mongodb database isn't running. Here is the warning:

```
> kerberos@0.0.17 install /Users/Sean/Desktop/Projects/crud/node_modules/kerberos
> (node-gyp rebuild) || (exit 0)

  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/kerberos/lib/kerberos.o
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/kerberos/lib/worker.o
  CC(target) Release/obj.target/kerberos/lib/kerberosgss.o
../lib/kerberosgss.c:509:13: warning: implicit declaration of function 'gss_acquire_cred_impersonate_name' is invalid in C99
      [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
        maj_stat = gss_acquire_cred_impersonate_name(&min_stat,
                   ^
1 warning generated.
  CC(target) Release/obj.target/kerberos/lib/base64.o
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/kerberos/lib/kerberos_context.o
  SOLINK_MODULE(target) Release/kerberos.node
```

Comment: That means it can't connect to your MongoDB server at 127.0.0.1 (localhost) port 27017, probably it's down.

Comment: Thanks. I didn't realize the mongodb server wasn't up

Answer (score 2):

It can happen when the mongodb service is not running on your machine.So start with below command it will be help you to open node server with no interrupt as well as mongodb will also run on default port.

> brew services start mongodb